# How to Display link text over advertisement in bottom corner

Tags: html, css

I have a advertisement as given in below given jsfiddle.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgzobpds/)

HTML

```
  <div class='pc_singleblock'>
  <div style='box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; text-align:center; font-size: 11px; font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; width:300px; height:250px; background:#E7E7E7; color:#666; line-height:250px;position:relative;'
  class='pc_block_active'>
    <a target='_blank' href='//cdn.adclerks.com/core/adclick/3485/3329' alt='Followlike' title='Followlike' style='width: 300px; height: 250px;'><img width=300 height=250 src='//static.adclerks.com/ads/3485.jpg' /></a>
    <div class="tag">Adtext</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
      <style type='text/css'>.pc_block a {
    color: #666!important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .pc_block a:hover {
    color: #222!important;
  }

  .pc_block {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .pc_block:hover {
    margin: 0;
    background: #ddd;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
  }

  .pc_block_inactive {
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
  }

  .pc_block_inactive:hover {
    border: 1px solid #999;
  }

  </style>
```

I want to show adtext on this advertisement as show on demo ads on this page
[Demo ads](http://demo.xyzscripts.com/xyz-admarket/index.php?page=demo/demo) in the bottom right corner. which initially show any symbol and change to link on hover as shown on this demo page. How to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can position your link

```
  .pc_block_active {position: relative;}
  .tag {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
  }
```

Hope this work

Comment: also want to change this div content on mouse hover